# ASP.Net MVC 2,0 EditorForModel Question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, editorformodel

I have written an Enum extension method that allows me to create a view model and allows me to easily bind a generic Enum to a SelctList like:

```
this.ProductStatusList = new ProductStatusTypes().BindToSelectList<ProductStatusTypes>  
(product.Status.ToString());
```

In my View I can then have:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>               
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <%= Html.EditorForModel() %>                  
        <%=Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.ProductStatusList, new 
                                SelectList(Model.ProductStatusList, "Value", "Text",   
                                Model.Status.ToString()))%>               
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Notice I am using EditorForModel and then a seperate DropDownList.

My question is:  Is there a way to get the EditorForModel to be clever enough to pick up that I want to use a SelectList instead of a TextBox for status?

Many Thanks

Ted

Answer (score 1):

EditorForModel pays attention to a UIHint Attribute on your Properties. It will check if you have an Editor template for that UI Hint and try to use that for your form.